# Why isn't the bubbleDown method working as intended (Heap Sort)?

Tags: java, heapsort

This was an assignment that was due, and I attempted it in both C++ and Java, but in both versions, the bubbleDown method wasn't working as intended, though I believe the logic says it should. I've already handed in both versions, but since the Java version is the most recent, I'll post it here.

Here's the Java version:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeapSort {
    static int[] heap;
    Integer[] sorted;
    String in, out;
    int fullLength = 0;

    public HeapSort(String inf, String outf) throws FileNotFoundException {
        in = inf;
        out = outf;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(in));
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            fullLength++;
            scan.nextInt();
        }

        sorted = new Integer[fullLength];
        heap = new int[fullLength+1];
        heap[0] = 0;

        scan.close();
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return heap[0] == fullLength;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return heap[0] == 0;
    }

    public void buildHeap() throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(in));
        while (scan.hasNextInt())
            insertOneDataItem(scan.nextInt());

        scan.close();
    }

    public void deleteHeap() throws IOException {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            deleteRoot();
            printHeap();
        }
    }

    public void deleteRoot() throws IOException {
        if (isEmpty())
            return;

        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(out, true);
        f.write("Deleting " + heap[1] + "\n");
        f.close();
        int i;
        for(i = 0; sorted[i] != null; i++);
        sorted[i] = heap[1];
        heap[1] = heap[heap[0]--];
        bubbleDown();
    }


    public void insertOneDataItem(int num) throws IOException {
        if (isFull()) {
            p("Heap is full");
            return;
        }

        heap[++heap[0]] = num;
        bubbleUp();
        printHeap();
    }

    public void printHeap() throws IOException {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(out, true);
        f.write("Current Heap:\t");
        for (int i = 1; i <= heap[0]; i++) {
            if (i > 10) break;
            f.write(heap[i] + " ");
        }
        f.write("\n");
        f.close();
    }

    public void printSorted() throws IOException {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(out, true);
        f.write("Current Sorted:\t");
        for (int i = 1; i <= sorted.length; i++) {
            if (i > 10) break;
            f.write(sorted[i] + " ");
        }
        f.write("\n");
        f.close();
    }

    public void bubbleUp() {
        int h = heap[0];
        while (h >= 2 && heap[h] < heap[h/2]) {
            int x = heap[h];
            heap[h] = heap[h/2];
            heap[h/2] = x;
            h = h/2;
        }
    }

    public void bubbleDown() {
        int k = 1;
        // make sure we have at least a left child
        // before continuing on
        while (2*k <= heap.length) {
            int left = 2*k;
            int right = 2*k+1;
            if (heap[k] >= heap[left]) {
                int x = heap[k];
                heap[k] = heap[left];
                heap[left] = x;
                k = left;
                continue;
            }
            if (right <= heap.length &&
                heap[k] >= heap[right]) {
                int x = heap[k];
                heap[k] = heap[right];
                heap[right] = x;
                k = right;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void begin() throws IOException {
        buildHeap();
        deleteHeap();
        printSorted();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            p("Please start with: program file1.txt file2.txt");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // empty the output file
        (new FileOutputStream(args[1])).close();

        (new HeapSort(args[0], args[1])).begin();

    }

    public static void p(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The input file (args[0]) with have only integers in the file, with some on the same row, and on different lines. args[1] is the output file name.

When the program goes through bubbleDown, it starts to work as intended in the beginning, but then it skips some numbers, and towards the end I'll eventually see a number that should have been at the top. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks suspicious for a number of reasons.  1 -- you are mixing the actual data structure implementation with reading a file which makes no sense.  Very hard to follow.  Then this piece can't be right:

```
sorted[i] = heap[1];
heap[1] = heap[heap[0]--];
```

First line suggests that heap array contains actual data elements.
But second line is treating heap contents as indexes of some sort?  heap[0]-- will decrement the value stored at location 0 of the heap array, but first it will use it to move the contents of heap[heap[0]] to heap[1]? What?  Are you using heap[0] as a special thing to store the index of the last element in the array?  I suggest you start by rewriting code w/o hacks like this, it should make it easier to understand and fix.  In reality your heap should start at element 0 and your left node will be at 2k+1 and right will be at 2k+2.

Now this smells like it is wrong:

```
right <= heap.length
```

you should be comparing right to that terrible heap[0], because heap.length will not be shrinking when you remove things from it.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sorted.length; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
```

and the final *main* mistake is in the bubbleDown method.  When bubbling down you need to be swapping the downward shifting node with the *smaller* of its children.  So that is 7 is bubbling down and its left child is 6 and right child is 4, you need to swap 7 and 4, otherwise you get invalid tree of

```
   6
 /   \
7     4
```

So code should be

```
if (heap[k] >= heap[left] && heap[left] < heap[right]) {
```

You are welcome.  And your professor owes me lunch for doing his job for him.

Comment: The way we were taught in class was to use heap[0] as the total number of elements in the current heap, starting the actual heap at heap[1], and using 2k for left child and 2k+1 for right child.

Comment: that is pretty terrible, seriously.

Comment: btw try to think about how you would solve it 30 years ago before there was internet.  (hint: it would involve printing your tree after each operation, manually looking at to verify that it still satisfies the invariant of the heap tree)